# In iOS how to get object fromViewController name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know that this is double question. I know that I can use property in `toViewController` to get name of UIViewController to get NSString which tells me where I am coming from.

Anyway I want to ask if there a simple way to get name of `UIViewController` when `unwinding` from `segue`.

I have a `UIViewController` with `segues` to 3 forms. I programatically return to that view controller. I need to run a specific code only when I am returning from one of view controllers. My goal is using string from name of `fromViewController` start that specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIViewController` by `NSString` from its class name isn't safe enough because the name can be changed.
You can use `isKindOfClass` instead:

```
       UIViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       if ([destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewControllerClass1 class]]) {
        // put code related to transition to MyViewControllerClass1
        }
        else if ([destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewControllerClass2 class]]) {
       // put code related to transition to MyViewControllerClass2
        }
```

Comment: 10x this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString * identifier = destinationViewController.identifier;
    NSString * title = destinationViewController.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom delegate method in the primary VC, create 3 strings with unique name so that u can identify. 
EG.

```
 NSString* stringFrmFORM1, *stringFrmFORM2, *stringFrmFORM3;
 -(void)setString:(NSString*)myString{
    //set the string from the VC1,2,3 to each string based on Primary VC's strings
 }
```

Call the delegate method from each registration VC, and set those Strings.

You will have your registration strings to each of the Unique strings that you have set, from each of the Registration VC's.

Comment: This solution is correct, but I actually don't want to add additional properties for my view controller. I want to use object returned from unwind segue and use it to know where I am coming from. Sorry but my reputation does not allow me to vote up for your answer.

Comment: No problem :) But make sure you dont get your segue in a circular loop, that would make VC objects overlap and keep on increasing memory. 
Use delegate when u got to return to previous VC from the next Segue .
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your base question, you can get the name of a class in string form with:

```
NSString *strClassName = NSStringFromClass([fromViewController class]);
```

---

but as @AlexPeda pointed out in ze answer, `-isKindOfClass:` would be better.

```
if ([fromViewController isKindOfClass:[SpecificViewController class]]) {    
    //run your 'specific' code
}
```